# How add WKWebView on TableView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I'm trying to make a simple application mapping data from the network to the table. But the site requires the authorization of OAuth 2.0 and the receipt of the token. Wanted to programmatically show a view with a WKWebView for this. I do this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: tableView.bounds.height), configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        tableView.addSubview(webView)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.ru/")!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idFriendCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
}
```

but, seperators TableView are overlapping my WebView:
[image]
How to do it right?

Comment: Do you need to show webView and tableView simultaneously?

Comment: no, show i need something one. the program is one TableViewController, I wanted show a WebView for authorization and to get the token(from the address bar) and close WebView. I'm just learning to create elements programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you have 2 simple solution here.

1) You can create custom `UIViewController`, replacing your `TableViewController`. That inherit `UIViewController` not `UITableViewController`. Add manually `tableView` there, conform `controller` to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` if needed. Then add `webView` to its `view`.

2) You can create new `controller`, add `webView` to it. Then [present](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) new `controller` within your `TableViewController`

Comment: I can create a new ViewController and add a WebView to it programmatically (without storyboard)? And then show it on top of mу TableViewController?

Comment: @flowGlen. yes, you can. If you will encounter troubles with it. Write - I will expand my answer